# Can we choose from different attribute group in xsd?

Tags: xsd

Can we do the following? If not, can you guide me to choose the attribute group in xsd.

```
<xsd:complexType name="getGroupType">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="groupA"/>
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="groupB"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xsd:choice` is called a model group and can only be used with elements, not with attributes. However, it may be possible to emulate a choice on an attribute group using subtypes (two types extending a base one).